# How to delete an element of an array in an Ethereum contract?

Tags: raw-data, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am wondering - is it possible to delete a single element of an array in Ethereum without having to create a new array and copying the entire array? Reading [some of the documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Tutorial), I can't seem to find any good way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the operation of removing an element from a list to be efficient (i.e. without having to copy the list), you have to use a different data structure, e.g. a linked list or a mapping with a reverse index. Note that `delete arr[ind]` does not rearrange the array but only resets the array element.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [the documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Tutorial#arrays):

```
delete myArray[arrayIndex];
```